# Jagged edges on canvas shape when colours change

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I currently have an issue whereby changing the fillStyle of a canvas is causing a smooth diagonal line to turn jagged and I don't know why.

I've created a JSBin where you can see the effect here: http://jsbin.com/fadeyiva/1/edit

I've set the background colour to black so you can more easily see the canvas and the jagged edge. The grey shape is the canvas, if you scroll down to the bottom of the page and then back up it should trigger the waypoint and change the canvas colour to orange.

However, if you look at the bottom diagonal line it starts off smooth when it's grey but when it changes colour the edge becomes very jagged. I don't know why this is happening because the code is only changing the fillStyle, it's not altering the shape of the canvas at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your angled box is originally being drawn in your canvas with respect to dithering (this is taken care of natively). When you apply a fill change as you are, you throw out the idea of dithering and simply make every single pixel of the object the same color. The edges of the object need to blend with the background (thats what dithering means).

I suggest instead of just adjusting the fill value of the object, redraw the entire object as you did in your `window.onload()` function. Because you are calling a redraw, the browser will force the dithering on the object and adjust it for the new color.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but redrawing the entire object did indeed solve the issue, thank you :)

Comment: Thats ok. Glad I could help.